# php grabbing rss feeds from too many sources

Tags: php, rss, updates

The website I am working on has several rss resources from blogs inputed by users, so the number of resources is growing/changing.

At some point the resources are too many to be updated in one call (otherwise it takes too long and makes the script crash).

What alternatives exist to make possible to update feeds from multiple growing resources? in php if possible... or is this supposed to be done through node.js?

Comment: Try scheduling the updates or building a queue on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a queue system or look http://gearman.org/